# Operation not permitted with non root user

Tags: php, .htaccess, ftp

I´m getting a well known error:

> Warning: chmod() [function.chmod]: Operation not permitted in /home/NAME/domains/DOMAIN.NL/public_html/panel/ftp-directory.php on line 24
>   bool(false)

So I've looked online on how to fix it, and that's just my problem... I've a shared webhosting so I'm not the actual root user. And I can't change anything about that, no server changes etc. The only thing I can do is trough .htaccess or ini_set with a PHP file.

This is my code where it goes wrong:

```
$stringValue = 'nieuw';
$chmod = chmod('/home/rezamgn93/domains/rasolutions.nl/public_html/'.$stringValue, 0777);
var_dump($chmod);
```

I'm chmodding a map, and for know I can do it manually but I'm making an online FTP editor so I would like it to be automatically.

Thank you very much for helping in advance! English isn't BTW my mother language, I'm sorry for any mistakes. Happy holidays!

Comment: This doesn't sound like something you want to be doing. If you want to auto mask like this, perhaps look into setfacl?

Comment: @JonLin I've searched so much, and I have made the entire system already.. I'm sorry to turn your option down but I would like it to be on this way. And the problem with setfacl is that I can't run it on my shared webshoting, I need a VPS for that I'm guessing?